# Previous and Next Post in Same Taxonomy in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I have created a custom post type called staff and have a custom taxonomy called `staff-categories` which has terms like *Broker*, *Admin* etc etc .

I have created the single page `single-staff.php`. Im stuck in the navigation part where I need the previous and next navigation to be in the same taxonomy. The default `previous_post_link` and `next_post_link` just didnt' help.

I dont want to use a plugin either. Can someone please help me to fix this?

```
<span class="left"><?php previous_post_link( '%link',' %title' ); ?></span>
<span class="right"><?php next_post_link( '%link', '%title'); ?</span>
```

Comment: <span class="left"><?php previous_post_link( '%link',' %title' ); ?></span>
   <span class="right"><?php next_post_link( '%link', '%title'); ?></span>.

Comment: Well you can either use plugin or write your own functions that do that. It's not a default functionality of those two functions ;)

Comment: @miha Could you please tel me how to do it. I tried the plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/previous-and-next-post-in-same-taxonomy/ . But it doesnt display anything. Its just blank when the "true" argument is set

Answer (score 1):

I had met with the same question, and i found the solution here: 
http://bucketpress.com/next-and-previous-post-link-in-same-custom-taxonomy